# The value for annotation attribute Min.value must be a constant expression

Tags: java

Eclipse keeps giving me the error:

```
The value for annotation attribute Min.value must be a constant expression
```

But I am most definitely giving the annotation a constant.

```
private static final int MIN_YEAR = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR) - 1;

@Min(MIN_YEAR)
```

If I change it to be

```
private static final int MIN_YEAR = 2013;
```

It's perfectly happy, but I shouldn't have to do that. Does anyone know why or how my MIN_YEAR constant isn't considered a constant if it's declared with an evaluated expression instead of a plain number?

Comment: What is @Min from?  What library?

Comment: import javax.validation.constraints.Min;

Comment: -1 since the first hit on googling your question is a duplicate.  Please research before posting.  If I am wrong and this does not answer your question, then you should have explained that you researched it, and explain why this does not fit your needs.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2469473/variable-field-in-a-constraint-annotation

Comment: @djechlin I found that and read it. It does not answer my question. My question is about why there is a difference between the way the two constants are declared, not how to create an annotation that allows non-constants.

Comment: Okay, a little more subtle.  Answered here for instance:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3827393/java-switch-statement-constant-expression-required-but-it-is-constant

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The expression

```
private static final int MIN_YEAR = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR) - 1;
```

will be determined only in run-time, but

```
private static final int MIN_YEAR = 2013;
```

is determined in compilation time, so it's allowed since the values in the annotations should be resolved at compilation time and not runtime.

Comment: I suppose if the annotation runs at compile time that makes sense. I think that Eclipse's error message is somewhat misleading, though, since it says the problem is that it's not a `constant expression`, which both are. They just aren't both compile-time constant expressions, which is a little different.