# JSR-303 - computed value as argument?

Tags: java, annotations, bean-validation

I want to validate a field `birthYear` in way: "User's age has to be below 50."

So I want to use JSR-303 annotation validation like this:

```
@Max(Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR) - 50)
private int birthYear;
```

But the compiler says "Attribute value must be constant."

Is there a way to do it in a simple way, such as this? Or is it necessary to implement my own validator for that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [The value for annotation attribute Min.value must be a constant expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16744067/the-value-for-annotation-attribute-min-value-must-be-a-constant-expression)

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I wasn't able to google it.

Comment: But still, is there a way to do it? Easier than implementing custom validator?

Comment: Just copypaste the exact error message into search field. E.g. https://www.google.com/search?q=bean+validation+%22Attribute+value+must+be+constant%22

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your error message suggests, you cannot have expressions in annotation values and therefore you'll need to use a custom validation annotation.

It's relatively easy to do this:

*Annotation*

```
@Constraint(validatedBy = AgeConstraintValidator.class)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.PARAMETER})
public @interface MaxAge {

/**
 * The age against which to validate.
 */
int value();

String message() default "com.mycompany.validation.MaxAge.message";
Class<?>[] groups() default {};
Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

*Constraint Validator*

```
public class AgeConstraintValidator implements ConstraintValidator<MaxAge, Integer> {

private int maximumAge;

@Override
public void initialize(MaxAge constraintAnnotation) {
    this.maximumAge = constraintAnnotation.value();
}

@Override
public boolean isValid(Integer value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
    if (value == null) {
        return true;
    }

    return value.intValue() <= this.maximumAge;
}

}
```

Then you can just annotate your field with `@MaxAge(50)` and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the annotations params need to have a value that can be resolved at compile time, but the Call to `Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR)` can only be resolved at runtime thus the compiler error.

You are better off in this type of situation to write the validation logic in the setter logic, something like

```
public  void setBirthYear( int year){ 
   if( Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR) - year < 50) {
   {
     throw IllegalAgumentException()
   }
   this.birthYear = year;
}
```

The alternative is that you can write a custom JSR 303 Annotation something like `@VerifyAge(maxAge=50)` then in the handler for the annotation you can check that the value is less than 50.

See http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.0/reference/en-US/html/validator-customconstraints.html for details on how to write a custom validation annotation.

Answer (score 0):

If you’re using the Spring Framework then you can use the Spring Expression Language (SpEL) for that. I’ve wrote a small library that provides JSR-303 validator based on SpEL. Take a look at https://github.com/jirutka/validator-spring.

With this library you can write your validation like this:

```
@SpELAssert("#this < T(java.util.Calendar).getInstance().get(T(java.util.Calendar).YEAR) - 50")
private int birthYear;
```

However, the code to obtain the current year is quite ugly, isn’t it? Let’s put it into a helper class!

```
public class CalendarHelper {
    public static int todayYear() {
        return Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);
    }
}
```

And then you can do this:

```
@SpELAssert(value="#this < #todayYear() - 50", helpers=CalendarHelper.class)
private int birthYear;
```