# Custom validation annotation fails

Tags: java, spring-mvc

There is a custom validation annotation created to check if two spring form fields are equal or not.

PasswordVerification:

```
@Constraint(validatedBy = PasswordVerificationValidator.class)
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.FIELD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface PasswordVerification {
    String message() default "";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

}
```

PasswordVerificationValidator:

```
public class PasswordVerificationValidator implements ConstraintValidator<PasswordVerification, UserFormRegistration> {

    @Override
    public void initialize(PasswordVerification constraintAnnotation) {}

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(UserFormRegistration userFormRegistration, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        return userFormRegistration.getPassword().equals(userFormRegistration.getVerifyPassword());
    }
}
```

UserFormRegistration:

```
@PasswordVerification(message = "Password and password confirmation fields don't match")
public class UserFormRegistration {
    private String password;
...
```

So, if the annotation is applied to the class UserFormRegistration, it works fine. But if I want to apply it to the field (see below), it fails.

```
public class UserFormRegistration {
    @PasswordVerification(message = "Password and password confirmation fields don't match")
    private String password;
...
```

Exception:

```
javax.validation.UnexpectedTypeException: HV000030: No validator could be found for constraint 'ua.com.vertex.validators.interfaces.PasswordVerification' validating type 'java.lang.String'. Check configuration for 'password'
```

How to fix?

Comment: I think you can find the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2469473/variable-field-in-a-constraint-annotation

Comment: Thanks, it was useful

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to apply the annotation at method level also so you need to have `ElementType.METHOD`

so change `@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.FIELD})` to

```
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.FIELD,ElementType.METHOD})
```

so now @PasswordVerification will be applicable to methods, classes,interfaces,enums and fields

Comment: It didn't help. The same exception

Comment: @sva605 did you try to clean and run?

Comment: When applied to a string field instead of a class, ConstraintValidator wants to receive String, not a bean, i.e. ConstraintValidator<PasswordVerification, String> instead of ConstraintValidator<PasswordVerification, UserFormRegistration>. I didn't understand that from the very beginning and that's why exception was thrown