# spring validation for conditional constraints

Tags: spring, validation, spring-mvc, hibernate-validator

Please let me know if spring validation and/or jsr hibernate validator has support.

I need to hookup bean validation in the controller , preferably using the @valid annotation of the parameter.

1. In our beans I have properties with static constraints, such as range constraints etc.
2. for some properties [say, id, name] I need conditional constraints, such as, if the request from the client is a 'create' , id should be null and name must not be empty.
   If the request is for update/delete I need the id to be not null and name is irrelevant.

For the static constraints, I have the spring+hibernate validator working fine.
But, is there a way to achieve the conditional constraints?

Thank you

Comment: The best I could think of are [validation groups](http://beanvalidation.org/1.1/spec/#constraintdeclarationvalidationprocess-groupsequence)

Answer (score 2):

Using the `@ConstraintValidator` annotation this is possible, together with not putting any class level annotations in those two fields as those would apply all the time.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2781771/how-can-i-validate-two-or-more-fields-in-combination) an example of an address constraint validator, and further info on the [official doc](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.0.1/reference/en/html/validator-customconstraints.html#validator-customconstraints-constraintannotation).