# Spring validate nested object with condition on parent

Tags: spring, validation, hibernate-validator

What I want to achieve might be a bit weird but sadly I cannot change that easily. I have a DTO that has a nested resource. The nested resource gets validated and the validation it gets differs based on an attribute of its parent.

```
class rootDto {

  @NotEmpty
  private String type;

  @Valid
  private AddressDto address;

  // Other attributes follow ...
}
```

Now AddressDto looks like the following:

```
class AddressDto {

  @NotEmpty(/* ONLY IF rootDto.type IS 'xxx' */)
  private String name;

  @NotEmpty(/* ONLY IF rootDto.type IS 'yyy' */)
  private String street;

  // Other attributes follow ...
}
```

I read about class level contrains ([example answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2783859/1221734)) but I don't think that this is what I want. I could always create a `Validator` for the `rootDto` and inside that have the conditional validations for the `AddressDto` but that would be ugly and will grow way too much since `AddressDto` is not the only nested resource I have that requires such validation.

So my main question is, can I somehow expose to the nested resource attributes from its parent in order to use them for the validation? Is there an alternative I have not found/thought?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Hibernate Validator as Bean Validation provider and are happy to use a non standard feature, you can use Hibernate Validator's `GroupSequenceProvider` SPI - http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.2/reference/en-US/html_single/#__literal_groupsequenceprovider_literal

The idea would be to work with validation groups which you programmatically activate by using a `GroupSequenceProvider` on your `RootDto`.