# Custom class level bean validation constraint

Tags: constraints, bean-validation, class-level

I already know how to add annotation based validation on specific attributes in Entity class like :-

```
public class Person {

    @NotNull
    private String firstName;

    private String lastName;

    //...
}
```

But is it possible to add annotation on class Person, in order to validate all the attributes inside this class, by creating a Customised Validation Class and handling validation there  somewhere like :-

```
@Retention(value = RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)      
@Target(value = ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface PersonneName {
public String firstName();
}
```

I am working on a project to get Constraints from Database and creating Customised Validation Class and applying on the Entity class attributes according to the constaints got from DB.
Please suggest.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I validate two or more fields in combination?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2781771/how-can-i-validate-two-or-more-fields-in-combination)

Answer (score 5):

Yes, of course, it's possible. First, create the definition of your annotation. Pretty much like you did in your example, however, with a different `@Target` type

```
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = PersonValidator.class)    
public @interface ValidPerson {
    String message () default "Your custom message";
    Class<?>[] groups () default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload () default {};
}
```

Then implement the validator whose `isValid` method takes the instance of your Person class:

```
 public class PersonValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ValidPerson, Person> {
  
    @Override
    public boolean isValid (Person person, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        // your validation logic
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure it is possible, just check the documentation regarding how to write custom class level constraints - http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#section-class-level-constraints

The important thing of course is that you make sure that one can actually place the constraint annotation on the type level. For that you need to add `ElementType.TYPE` to the `@Target` annotation.

Comment: thanks @hardy.. So will it  be possible to handle validations of all the attributes of the entity Class , while annotating with the CustomValidator and handling all the validation there in CustomValidator

Comment: You will get passed the whole instance, so you have access to all its properties and methods. It is up to you do then develop the appropriate validation logic.

Comment: If you could provide small snippet that would help a lot