# java interface a varible value for annotation

Tags: java, annotations

How can this interface be redesigned or wrapped by another interface so it can be applied  (many times) but always with different value (not just 100) for the annotation: @MaxLength(X)

```
public interface FixedString{
    String getValue();
    void setValue(@NotNull @MaxLength(100) String value);
}
```

Your suggestions appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Since annotation only accepts compile-time constants, I'll suggest the usage of **cross field / class level** validation by introducing a max length field and validating `value` length against it.

Some references:

[How can I validate two or more fields in combination?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2781771/how-can-i-validate-two-or-more-fields-in-combination)

https://dwuysan.wordpress.com/2012/03/20/cross-field-validation-using-bean-validation-jsr-303/