# Class Level validation in Spring Form

Tags: java, spring, forms, validation, spring-mvc

I am new to Spring and am trying to make a validation form with internationalized validation messages.
I am using JSR @Valid annotation for my Login Form validation.

I want to perform the below 3 validations:

1. Check if username is empty
2. Check if password is empty.
3. Check if password is valid against username.

I am able to perform all these validations but the problem is that on my UI, I am getting the 3rd validation along with 1st and 2nd validation.

I want to display 3rd validation only when 1st and 2nd validations are passed.

Below is my jsp code :

```
                <label for="username"> <spring:message code="label.email" />                        </label>
                <form:input path="username" id="username" />
                <form:errors path="username" style="color: red" />
                <br />
                <br />
                <label for="password"> <spring:message
                        code="label.password" /></label>
                <form:input path="password" id="password" />
                <form:errors path="password" style="color: red" />
                <br />
                <form:errors path="authenticated" style="color: red" />
```

My controller code :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = {RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.GET})
public String authenticate(@ModelAttribute("user") @Valid User user,BindingResult result, ModelMap model, Locale locale, SessionStatus status, RedirectAttributes redirectAttrs, HttpServletRequest req){       

    if(result.hasErrors()){
        return "home";
    }

//code to validate password against username
}
```

My Bean Code

```
public class User implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -7788619177798333712L;

@NotEmpty(message = "Please enter your username.")
private String username;

@NotEmpty(message = "Please enter your password.")
private String password;

@AssertTrue(message= "Invalid username or password")
boolean authenticated;
```

It will be a big help if someone can guide me on this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can use class leven constraints rather than separate field for the validation.

See [Cross field validation with Hibernate Validator (JSR 303)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972933/cross-field-validation-with-hibernate-validator-jsr-303) and [How can I validate two or more fields in combination?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2781771/how-can-i-validate-two-or-more-fields-in-combination)

Just introduce your own annotation to check field combination in the validator class which implements Constraint or ConstraintValidator interfaces.

Then add the annotation to the form class.

Comment: Thank you, StanislavL, for your kind reply. I checked the links. My problem is that  I need to show in the UI either Validation 1 or 2 (not 3) or Validation 3 only (not 1  and 2), at a time.