# How to add conditional based @NotNull constraint in spring boot?

Tags: spring-boot, annotations

We are using `spring-boot`.
I want to add conditional based constraint in java class.
For e.g.

```
@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private Integer userId;
    @Column(name = "firstName")
    private String firstName;
    @Column(name = "lastName")
    private String lastName;
}
```

Now in above code I want to put `@NotNull` constraint on `lastName` property if and only if the `firstName` property is not empty.

Comment: At which point do you want the validation? saving the entity or at the point by populating the object?

Comment: have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2781771/how-can-i-validate-two-or-more-fields-in-combination, sinc your constraint is a constraint over 2 fields

Comment: @Patrick, I want the validation before saving the entity. And it is at the controller layer as I am using javax validation.

Comment: @parthivrshah A little late to the party, but you could instantiate the validator manually and then execute the validate method.  Like `validator.validate(payload);`

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you can use validation groups and a custom constraint validator to achieve conditional validation. Here's an example:

```
@Entity
public class User {
    ...

    @Column(name = "firstName")
    private String firstName;

    @ConditionalNotNull
    @Column(name = "lastName")
    private String lastName;

    ....
}
```

Now, define the ConditionalNotNull annotation and the corresponding ConditionalNotNullValidator:

```
import javax.validation.Constraint;
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidator;
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidatorContext;
import javax.validation.Payload;
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Target({ElementType.FIELD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = ConditionalNotNullValidator.class)
public @interface ConditionalNotNull {
    String message() default "Field must not be null if the condition is met";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

    String value() default "";
}
```

ConditionalNotNullValidator:

```
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidator;
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidatorContext;

public class ConditionalNotNullValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ConditionalNotNull, Object> {

    private String field;

    @Override
    public void initialize(ConditionalNotNull constraintAnnotation) {
        this.field = constraintAnnotation.value();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(Object value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        if (value == null) {
            return true; // Null values are accepted, let @NotNull handle it
        }

        try {
            // Use reflection to get the value of the condition field
            Object conditionFieldValue = value.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("get" + capitalize(field)).invoke(value);

            // Check the condition and validate accordingly
            return conditionFieldValue != null;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Error accessing condition field", e);
        }
    }

    private String capitalize(String s) {
        return s.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + s.substring(1);
    }
}
```

This way, the lastName field will only be validated with @NotNull if the firstName field is not empty. If firstName is empty, lastName is considered valid, regardless of its value.