# Get field name when javax.validation.ConstraintViolation is returned by validate method (Custom validator)

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-boot

There are sever questions around this topic. But I couldn't find any solution for this. 
When we write a custom validator to validate on multiple fields of a class **constraintViolation.getPropertyPath()** method will not return any value. 
Suppose I have written a custom class level validator something like this (https://stackoverflow.com/a/2783859/3725760) to validate on two fields like stateDate and enddate(startDate<= endDate). How can I get field names?

**EDIT:**

```
Set<ConstraintViolation<T>> constraintViolationSet = validator.validate(object);
    for (ConstraintViolation<?> constraintViolation : set) {
                stringBuilder.append(constraintViolation.getPropertyPath() + " ");
                stringBuilder.append(constraintViolation.getMessage() + ". ");
                stringBuilder.append(constraintViolation.getInvalidValue() + " ");
                stringBuilder.append("is not allowed");
            }
```

Comment: please add some code snipts that you have tried..

Comment: you may  go through with this link might help you out --->> https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-custom-validator

Comment: Thanks a lot for suggesting above link. I am able to do the validation for multiple fields. But my issue is when I try to get field names involved in violations I am getting an empty value when "constraintViolation.getPropertyPath()" method is called. Which generally return field name in case of field level custom validation

Comment: assign the variable by `setPropertyPath(args)` method (If verfication failed in custom Validator) and this will reflects if you try to get by calling `getPropertyPath()` Method