# How to validate two optional parameters, but one of them must be filled (Java)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, validation, swagger

I am describing request data parameter using Java, SpringBoot and Swagger.
Normally I would define which parameter is required using @ApiModelProperty or @NotBlank annotation.
But I have this case:
I have two parameters. Both are optional. But, when send this request data, one of two must be filled, otherwise validation error is expected.

```
public class ABC{
   @ApiModelProperty(notes="FieldA", required= false)
   @NotBlank
   String fieldA;

   String fieldB;
}
```

my question are

- How to validate this condition before sending the request to API server?
- Is there any available annotation to handle this input validation?
- Or there is no other way than handling it in the service server using if-else condition and check whether fieldA is null, then fieldB cannot be null, etc?

Comment: Something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2781771/how-can-i-validate-two-or-more-fields-in-combination

Comment: I  think `3rd` approach is much appropriate. Using `3rd` approach you have more control over it. Like `if(fieldA==null && fieldB==null){//throw validation error}`