# Java - Validating more than one field with only one annotation

Tags: java, spring, validation, annotations, bean-validation

I found a similar question and answer -> [How can I validate two or more fields in combination?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2783859/12367886)

But I want to make it reusable way without using inheritance.

For example, I want to write an annotation that checks that end date must be greater than start date.

```
class A {
    Date startDate;
    Date endDate;
}

class B {
    Date startDate;
    Date endDate;
}
```

According to the answer I linked, I need to write 2 separate annotations. How can I do it with single annotation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use reflection to get fields value.

1. In example you linked you need to add 2 fields to `@AddressAnnotation`:

- startDateFieldName
- endDateFieldName

2. Store them in `MultiCountryAddressValidator` in `initialize` method.
3. Change `implements ConstraintValidator<AddressAnnotation, Address>` to `implements ConstraintValidator<AddressAnnotation, Object>`
4. In `isValid` method use reflection to get actual values of start and end date.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is it the best and clean way? The point I insist on is actually not annotation. I'm trying to do with the cleanest way.

Comment: @Bose Probably yes. Or create some superclass with parent date-fields for A and B classes, so you can use this superclass in Validator. In other case you can't be sure which class you're going to check and how fields will be named in it.