# Can spring validation verify multiple fields at the same time?

Tags: java, spring, validation

I want to have a rest endpoint which returns all invalid input fields with a reason, which explains the invalidity.

For that, I need to implement a validation method in each DTO class, which will be received by the rest endpoint.
Now I'm asking myself if there is already a good approach to do that. I'm thinking about the spring validation. But I think there will be only thrown a "MethodArgumentNotValidException", which contains one invalid argument !?

Further, I could build a custom builder, but I think I can just define when the class is valid and when not and not change the error result: [How can I validate two or more fields in combination?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2781771/how-can-i-validate-two-or-more-fields-in-combination)

Is there an existing way to validate multiple arguments at the same time and to return a list of all invalid arguments with a reason?
Otherwise, I would build such a validation for my purpose.

T

€dit:
Okay, I found this https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-custom-validator
and the information that when I do this for validation I get a list of all messages and parameter names:

```java
        final ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
        final var validator = factory.getValidator();
        final Set<ConstraintViolation<DtoResponse>> violations = validator.validate(tmp);
        for (final ConstraintViolation<DtoResponse> violation : violations) {
            log.error(violation.getPropertyPath().toString() + " - " + violation.getMessage());
        }
```

Now I have a last problem. When I write a verification for a whole class (ElementType.TYPE) (https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-custom-validator#custom-class-level-validation) then the getPropertyPath() of the ConstraintViolation is empty.
Is there a way to insert there a name ?

Comment: Bean validation ConstraintViolationException contains all the validation errors.

Comment: okay thank you. I missed that fact. How can I ensure, that this exception will be thrown and not the "MethodArgumentNotValidException" ?
And how can I write own validators with this exception? I saw just the linked article above and there I overwrite a boolean isValid method, which returns true or false and no list of invalid arguments.