# Hibernate validator - field A or B can be empty, but both A and B cannot be empty

Tags: java, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

A bean class with multiple fields. When checking, if A is empty, check B, otherwise do not check B. And I need to set the message according to different checks.

I have many such validations, can hibernate validator be easily implemented?

Now I write like this

```java
public class Order
{
    private String a;
    private String b;
    
    //.... other fields
}

public class Validation
{
    public void valid(Order order) throws Exception
    {
        if (order.getA().isEmpty())
        {
            if (order.getB().isEmpty())
            {
                throw new Exception("xxx message ");
            }
        }
        
        //....
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I validate two or more fields in combination?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2781771/how-can-i-validate-two-or-more-fields-in-combination)

Comment: `if (order.getA().isEmpty() ^ order.getB().isEmpty() {
// ...
}
`

Comment: @XtremeBaumer Can I use ConstraintValidator to set the message according to different validations?

Comment: @Ulimp you can pass the message as a property of the annotation.

Answer (score 0):

well it is because when A is empty B is not even checked because the check goes around. To improve your if I would use this:

```
public class Order
{
    private String a;
    private String b;
    
    //.... other fields
}

public class Validation
{
    public void valid(Order order) throws Exception
    {
        if (order.getA().isEmpty() || order.getB().isEmpty())
        {
            throw new Exception("xxx message ");
        }
        
        //....
    }
}
```

Or you could use annotations to check whether the field is empty or null.

Comment: `if A is empty, check B, otherwise do not check B`