# Hibernate Embeddable: validate on post load

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, orm

I have an `@Embeddable` class with two fields: `type` and `value`. Both fields map to the corresponding database columns. The first one is `enum` and the latter one is an interface that has multiple implementations.

Only certain combinations of `type` and `value` are considered valid even if `type` and `value` are correct in isolation. How can I perform such validation, when I retrieve the entity that owns the `@Embeddable` from the database?

I could perform validation inside no-args-constructor of embeddable, but as far as I'm concerned, Hibernate creates new `@Embeddable` instance with no-args-constructor and then injects the values with Java Reflection API. Therefore, if I access these two fields inside the constructor they will be `null`.

Is there an approach to register some `PostLoad` hook for the `@Embeddable` classes that Hibernate will trigger? I though about declaring `PostLoad` inside the entity itself and then calling `MyEmbeddable.validate` directly. But I think it's a dirty approach.

Comment: Why not make sure that the combination is valid before inserting?

Comment: @XtremeBaumer Of course, I do such validations before inserting. Anyway, I still want to be sure that I read correct data. Because there are already some rows in the database, when I implement this feature.

Comment: I think I found possible solution. Will try to implement it
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2781771/how-can-i-validate-two-or-more-fields-in-combination

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the class-level annotation to validate the whole object. It did work. Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2781771/how-can-i-validate-two-or-more-fields-in-combination) for more details.