# hibernate validator for cross field validation

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-validator

I have a question about hibernate validator:

```
class A
{
  private String a;
  private String b;
}
```

String a and b can either be null but can't both be null. How can I use Hibernate Validator to validate this case?

Thanks,

Comment: Pretty sure this is a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972933/cross-field-validation-with-hibernate-validator-jsr-303

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a custom class level validator to do this.

From the [Hibernate Validator Reference](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html/index.html):

- [Class-level constraints](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html/chapter-bean-constraints.html#d0e380)
- [Creating Custom Constraints](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html/validator-customconstraints.html)