# Unit testing JSR-303 validation in Spring

Tags: spring, hibernate-validator

I am trying to add a unit test for an annotated bean in spring using JSR-303 validation.

The bean is a simple one like this:

```
public class Bean {
   @Size(max=XX)  
   String text;  
}
```

In the Spring config I have the all the necessary JAR-files:

```
 validation-api  
 hibernate-validator
```

The validator is initialized with:

```
<bean id="validator" class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean" />
```

My attempt at a testcase looks like this (the spring and other fluff removed):

```
@Autowired
private LocalValidatorFactoryBean factory;


@Test
public void testTemplateFormBeanValidation() {
// TODO exception at the moment. Can not resolve the validator. Provider issue.
factory.setProviderClass(HibernateValidator.class);
factory.setTraversableResolver(new DefaultTraversableResolver());
Validator val = factory.getValidator();
TemplateFormBean fb1 = new TemplateFormBean();
fb1.setText("this text works");
Set<ConstraintViolation<TemplateFormBean>> constraints = val.validate(fb1);
assertNull(constraints);

}
```

When I run this test I get the following stacktrace:

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: javax/persistence/spi/PersistenceProvider.getProviderUtil()Ljavax/persistence/spi/ProviderUtil;
at javax.persistence.Persistence$1.isLoaded(Persistence.java:78)
at org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.JPATraversableResolver.isReachable(JPATraversableResolver.java:62)
at org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.DefaultTraversableResolver.isReachable(DefaultTraversableResolver.java:94)
at org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.SingleThreadCachedTraversableResolver.isReachable(SingleThreadCachedTraversableResolver.java:47)
at org.hibernate.validator.engine.ValidatorImpl.isValidationRequired(ValidatorImpl.java:757)
at org.hibernate.validator.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraint(ValidatorImpl.java:324)
at org.hibernate.validator.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForRedefinedDefaultGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:273)
at org.hibernate.validator.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForCurrentGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:256)
at org.hibernate.validator.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateInContext(ValidatorImpl.java:210)
at org.hibernate.validator.engine.ValidatorImpl.validate(ValidatorImpl.java:119)
at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.SpringValidatorAdapter.validate(SpringValidatorAdapter.java:145)
at general.TestValidationBeans.testTemplateFormBeanValidation(TestValidationBeans.java:30)
```

Am I missing some dependencies? I am using Hibernate with JPA2 annotations as persistence, so all those JARs exist and are working.

The version of Hibernate is:

```
2011-04-19 08:37:47 [INFO] Version - Hibernate Commons Annotations 3.2.0.Final
2011-04-19 08:37:47 [INFO] Environment - Hibernate 3.6.2.Final
2011-04-19 08:37:47 [INFO] Environment - hibernate.properties not found
2011-04-19 08:37:47 [INFO] Environment - Bytecode provider name : javassist
...
2011-04-19 08:37:47 [INFO] Version - Hibernate Validator 4.1.0.Final
```

Why isn´t Hibernate logging the version of hibernate-annotations? According to docs it is bundled from hibernate 3.5 in hibernate3.jar which I am using.
Should I see log output for hibernate annotations (something like "Version - Hibernate Annotations 3.4.0 GA)?

Comment: I can add that it works using this code in a controller: @Valid TemplateFormBean fb, BindingResult result. So I believe I am missing some configuration when using this programmatically.

Comment: I get same error running WebSphere Application Server 7 which has bundeled JPA 1.0 and is messing up hibernates JPA 2.0 implementation. So my guess is that somewhere in your classpath you have JPA 1.0 classes

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have a simpler set-up using context configuration as follows:

**MyTest.java**

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration
public class MyTest {

    @Autowired
    private Validator validator;


    @Test
    public void testMyForm() {
        final MyForm form = new MyForm();
        .
        .
        final Set<ConstraintViolation<MyForm>> violations = validator.validate(form);
        assertTrue(violations.isEmpty());
    }
}
```

**MyTest-context.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id="validator"
        class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean" />

</beans>
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion and I still get the original error: `java.lang.AbstractMethodError: javax/persistence/spi/PersistenceProvider.getProviderUtil()Ljavax/persistence/spi/ProviderUtil;
at javax.persistence.Persistence$1.isLoaded(Persistence.java:78)`. Very weird as it works perfectly when deployed, it sure looks like a version inconsistency or missing server jars, as @duffymo says, but I cant find the error.

Comment: I recently updated all Hibernate validation JARs to 4.2.0 final and Hibernate JPA 2 API to 1.0.1 final. Still no success.

Comment: I came back to this specific question on another project, and this time it worked flawlessly by injecting a Validator in the testcase instead of ValidatorFactory. I basically let Spring sort out loading the provider. So this answer is correct for me. I am using Hibernate Validator 5.0.1 and Spring 3.1.x.

Answer (score 0):

I think this says you've got a version problem.  The version of the JPA JAR that you have has a different method signature from the one that Spring expects.  Try updating the JARs to use the ones from Spring and see if that helps.

Comment: Hi, I investigated your suggestion but could not see version inconsistencies. I have updated the question with the versions I am using.