# Append type level validation error message to specific field

Tags: java, validation, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

I've got a simple class which get's validated using the `boolean isValid()` method, which works and of course the error message is at class/type level.

Here's my simple class:

```
public class NewPasswordDTO {
    @NotNull
    public String password;

    @NotNull
    public String confirmation;

    @AssertTrue(message="Passwords must match.")
    protected boolean isValid() {
        return password.equals(confirmation);
    }
}
```

But what I really want is something like that:

```
public class NewPasswordDTO {
    @NotNull
    @Equals("confirmation", message="...")
    public String password;

    @NotNull
    public String confirmation;
}
```

So the error message would be set at field level and not at class/type level.

Is this possible somehow? Maybe using a custom Validator for that class?

Thanks in advance!

### SOLUTION:

Thanks to Gunnar! I've just came up with a nice, universal solution `:-)`. I simply used (means copy & paste) the code from Hibernates `@ScriptAssert` and `ScriptAssertValidator` and modified it slightly:

`@ScriptAssert`:

- Add new `String field()`. (this is where the error message gets appended)

`ScriptAssertValidator`:

- Inside the `initialize` method, make sure to also save the `fieldName` and `message` properties, because we need to access them in the next step
- Add this snippet at the bottom of `isValid` method:

  `context.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate(errorMessage)
      .addPropertyNode(fieldName).addConstraintViolation();`
- Also add `context.disableDefaultConstraintViolation();` somewhere inside the `isValid` method to not generate the default error message which else would get appended at class level.

And that's it. Now I can use it like that:

```
@FieldScriptAssert(lang="javascript", script="_this.password.equals(_this.confirmation)", field="password", message="...")
public class NewPasswordDTO { ... }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer : It is not (unless you implement it) :http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/validation/constraints/package-summary.html shows all annotation constraints.
Of course you could inject your string as a resource in your class by @producer and so on (which recently is discussed to be removed in jdk8), but you could not use this value for your assert. 
 In reply to the comment: 
This was asuming that the nature is a constant string which you would like to use as a string resource.And then of course it is possible to write your own class based on java.lang.string with a @Producer which is then @Inject - able. Though it is certainly not the way I personally would deal with constant strings.

Comment: Thank you. I know all those annotations, the question was more like: Can I write my own Annotation/Validator which can handle this? ... And I don't really understand what you mean with "Of course you could inject your string as a resource in your class by @producer and so on". Do you have an example?

Comment: Wow, that sounds really like a baaaad hack `:-D`. Isn't it even possible to somehow use `@ScriptAssert(...)` for my task? ... (It's also dirty, but) maybe there's a possibility to do something like that: `@ScriptAssert(lang="javascript", script="if(!_this.password.equals(_this.confirmation)) password=''; return true;")`. Then I'd have some `@NotEmpty` check at `password` which catches that new provoked error...

Comment: I appended my custom solution at the top. Instead of an inflexible custom annotation, I decided to use the logic of `@ScriptAssert`. Pretty awesome!!

Answer (score 2):

You either could use the `@ScriptAssert` constraint on the class (note that a constraint should always be side-effect free, so it's not a good idea to alter the state of the validated bean; instead you should just check whether the two fieldss match) or you implement a custom class-level constraint.

The latter [also allows](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#section-custom-property-paths) to point to a custom property path for the constraint violation, which it allows to mark the "confirmation" property as erroneous instead of the complete class.

Comment: That's good news! I'll check that. Btw. I tried to alter state using `@ScriptAssert`, which is useless. The debug log always looked like: `some field constraint checked`, `some other field constraint checked`, `...`, `class constraint checked`. So no chance to trigger some field level constraint.

Answer (score 1):

If you’re using the Spring Framework, then as an alternative to the `@ScriptAssert` using a [JSR 223](https://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=223) scripting, you can use the [@SpELAssert](https://github.com/jirutka/validator-spring) that uses the Spring Expression Language (SpEL). The advantage is that it doesn’t need any JSR 223 compliant scripting engine which may not be available on some environments. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15672136/2217862) for more information.

Comment: Thank you. This sounds nice as well. Your provided code is really small and looking at the test cases it seems like the used expressions are pretty similar to those javascript expressions. ... Can you tell me which environment doesn't have support JSR 223? I thought it's part of Java since version 6?