# Bind global errors generated from form validation to specific form fields in spring 

Tags: spring, binding

Is it possible to do that?
I have made a custom annotation that checks if 2 fields are equal from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972933/cross-field-validation-with-hibernate-validator-jsr-303).
I would like to validate if a field "password" is equal to another field "confirmedPassword". Now if they are not, I'd like the error message to be displayed linked to the confirmedPassword field.
I display errors in jsp with `<form:errors path="" />`. Is there another way to do this?
Also there could also be another 2 fields in this annotation `email` and `confirmedEmail`. How could I make the distinction between which global error to put where...

I hope it all makes sense..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This thread from the Hibernate Validator forums seems to indicate that you want to add something like the following code to your custom validator's isValid() method:

https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=1003351&view=next

```
constraintValidatorContext.disableDefaultConstraintViolation();
constraintValidatorContext.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate( errorMessage ).addNode("confirmPassword").addConstraintViolation();
```

The `.addNode("confirmPassword")` bit looks from the docs like it will customize the path of the error:

http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/validation/ConstraintValidatorContext.html#buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate%28java.lang.String%29

Then you should be able to show just the error for confirmPassword by using `path="confirmPassword"` in your error tag.