# @RequestParam validation

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-mvc

Is there a way to validate request parameter with spring without checking it in every function?
For example, every method in a controller produces list of elements and each method accept 'from' and 'to' parameters, so the validation is:
`from >=0 && to > 0 && from < to`

I want to configure spring to return `BAD_REQUEST` or some other status just like it does when it cannot convert string to int parameter.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you use form-backing objects using `@RequestBody`, then you can use JSR-303 bean validation, where you annotate your form bean.  See http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#validation-beanvalidation for full details.  Then you don't need to bother with `Validator` objects or other coding - you just annotate.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not a form.

Comment: If its not a client-side HTML `<form>`, that doesn't matter; Spring on the server doesn't know anything about HTML forms.  It will still automatically map name-value pairs from the request to a Command object configured via `@RequestBody`.

Comment: Here's a question that has a full JSR-303 validator implementation in the accepted answer.  You can modify it to suit your case. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972933/cross-field-validation-with-hibernate-validator-jsr-303

Answer (score 0):

Directly - no. But if you wrap them in a class, you can have a `Validator` that `.supports(YourClass.class)` and `validate(..)` it.

```
public class Range {
   private int from;
   private int to;
   //setters & getters
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to wrap parameters of request mapping such as /users?from=1&to=20.