# Spring MVC 3 Validation annotations - Confirm email

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-mvc, bean-validation

I am trying to validate a form using Spring with integrated JSR-303 validations with Hibernate implementation. I have a "confirm email" (`emailConf`) field that I would like to confirm is equal to the `email` field. I saw a post of someone doing it like this:

```
public class ContactInfoForm {

    @NotEmpty
    private String name;

    @NotEmpty
    @Email
    private String email;

    @Expression(value = "emailConf= email", applyIf = "emailConf is not blank")
    private String emailConf;

    ...
}
```

However, this `emailConf` validation is not working (i.e. no error occurs when the fields don't match). I've seen a couple tutorials that have shown similar annotations, but can't find them anymore or any documentation on how this works. Does anyone know a way to validate "confirm email/password" fields through annotation? I am currently using the alternative, which is to implement `Validator` and validate the confirm fields in the validate method.

Comment: Where is this `@Expression` annotation from?

Comment: I didn't realize it, but the @Expression annotation is from "spring-modules" which I didn't even realize was still in my classpath. I had put this in my classpath when I was originally following a validation tutorial, but ended up using JSR-303 and Hibernate Validator. I'm not very familiar with spring-modules, but the forum page on SpringSource has an announcement from Aug 2010 saying "Spring Modules forum decommissioned in favor of Spring Extensions". If it's no longer supported, I would prefer not to use this library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May you should have look at this [question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1972933/280244): there are many ways discussed how to do a such a validation (it is about password and password confirm, but the problem is the same).

Comment: I'm using an implementation based on that FieldMatch validator and it works great.

Comment: I took a look at the page, and there are some really good resources there. One thing I can't figure out is how to associate the result of a class-level constraint to a specific field of my form. If the emails don't match, I would like my jsp to output the error as an error of the emailConf field. I am currently outputting errors using springs form:errors tag: `<form:errors path="emailConf" cssClass="formerrors" />`

Comment: Thanks for the resource. The custom FieldMatch annotation seems like a good way to do it. I also was able to get scriptassert working for my needs, but my code was a little messy getting the error to bind to the appropriate form field. In the end, I just ditched annotations and went with a custom validator class. If I had more time I would have experimented with these other solutions. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a ["Class-level constraint"](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.1/reference/en-US/html_single/#d0e326) (as described by JSR-303) if you want to compare 2 field of the same class. I don't think your `@Expression` will work that way.