# Play Framework Validation Matching Fields

Tags: java, playframework

For all my form submissions, I am creating documents to take in the submitted information

e.g. 
    public static void formAction(@Valid FormDocument formDocument){
    ...
    }

I like this as it keeps my controllers looking tidy and makes it easier to see what is being requested in a form.

My registration document looks (trimmed) like this:

```
@Email
@Required
public String email;
@Required
public String password;
@Required
public String confirmPassword;
```

My question is is there a way I can check that the password matches the confirmPassword field within this class itself. Currently I am checking in the controller and passing a validation message back in if it fails. I think it would be neater if it was done inside the document itself.

Thanks for any feedback/answers in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cross field validation with Hibernate Validator (JSR 303)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972933/cross-field-validation-with-hibernate-validator-jsr-303)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [Play documentation](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/validation-builtin#equals), they have your exact use case.

> **Equals**
>
> Checks that the value is equal to another parameter’s value, using the
>   value’s equals method, e.g. for checking for a password confirmation
>   field.
>
> Annotation syntax:
>
> `@Equals("passwordConfirmation") String password`

So, all you would need is

```
@Email
@Required
public String email;
@Equals("confirmPassword") 
public String password;
@Required
public String confirmPassword;
```

Comment: @Codemwnci Do you know How I do this in scala?

Comment: @karthi read this https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaForms , it shows how to create a form, set constraints and then validate it, It is very different to Play 1 (I assume when you say scala you mean play 2), but it is all there.