# How to create a custom validator annotation in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-boot

I would like to validate both the `@RequestBody` as well as path parameters.  Ideally, I'd like to create my own `@CustomValid` annotation instead of the `@Valid` one.

In addition to doing checks like `@NotNull` on the DTO itself, I want to actually check if say, the id of the object to be updated actually exists in the database. For example for this request:

```
{
  "id": "2348291983918",
  "name": "Carol"
}
```

I'd like to do a lookup for whether the users mongo collection actually contains an object with the id passed in or reject it.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Rather than using validators for this, I usually do the DB lookup in my code, and then throw an exception if the ID doesn't exist. Then I use `@ExceptionHandler` to map that exception to a 404 error.

Comment: An Easy why could be perform a method which starts by 'is', add  annotation @assertTrue and return a boolean, then validation checks it. your method could be as next exmaple:  public boolean isCorrectId(){  if(yourrepository.findbyId(id) != null) return true; else return false;  }. More info: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13012400/4751165

Comment: Otherwise validate your pathvariable it's not possible at the moment: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-6380 You must do it programmatically