# JSR Validations for dependent variables

Tags: java, validation, hibernate-validator, jsr

I am writing JSR validation for following inputs.

```
@JsonProperty(value = "state")
@NotEmpty
private String state;

@JsonProperty(value = "zipValue")
@NotEmpty
@Zip
private String zip;

@JsonProperty(value = "countryName")
@NotEmpty
@CountryAddress
private String countryName;
```

I am getting inputs from 2 countries. Hence state list and zip code format of countries are different.I want to validate both zip and state in the CountryAddress annotation itself.Could someone help me on this.?

Answer (score 0):

You can use class level constraints to validate field combination of the form. Just introduce a new validation and assign it to the class rather than fields.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9284450/jsr-303-validation-if-one-field-equals-something-then-these-other-fields-sho) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2781771/how-can-i-validate-two-or-more-fields-in-combination)