# Hibernate Validator conditionally

Tags: java, hibernate

I´ve been reading a lot about hibernate validator and so far I haven´t found the issue, that I want to resolve.
I want to validate some fields if the other attribute is equal to something for example:

```
@NotNull
String field1;
@NotNull
@Validate(field1 = "1")
String field2;
```

In this case I want to validate field2 if field1 is equal to "1"

Is it possible?

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9284450/jsr-303-validation-if-one-field-equals-something-then-these-other-fields-sho

Comment: as @JeanCedron linked... yes... it's possible but not easy... :)