# Hibernate -validator group sequence provider getDefaultSequenceProvider gets null as input

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate-validator

I am using the hibernate validator group sequence and want to execute the groups in a sequence based on business rules. But the input to the groupSequenceProvider for its getValidationGroups is always null, and hence custom sequence never gets added.

My request object:

```
@GroupSequenceProvider(BeanSequenceProvider.class)
public class MyBean {

    @NotEmpty
    private String name;

    @NotNull
    private MyType type;

    @NotEmpty(groups = Special.class)
    private String lastName;

    // Getters and setters        
}
```

Enum type:

```
public enum MyType {
    FIRST, SECOND
}
```

My custom sequence provider:

```
public class BeanSequenceProvider implements DefaultGroupSequenceProvider<MyBean> {

    @Override
    public List<Class<?>> getValidationGroups(MyBean object) {

        final List<Class<?>> classes = new ArrayList<>();
        classes.add(MyBean.class);
        if (object != null && object.getType() == MyType.SECOND) {
            classes.add(Special.class);
        }
        return classes;
    }
}
```

Group annotation:

```
public interface Special {
}
```

When I execute the above code, I get the input MyBean object as null and cannot add the custom sequence. What am I missing? I am using hibernate-validator version as  5.4.1.Final

Comment: Could you solve this issue? I am facing the same problem. I implemented the answer from here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/41849396/3238085

Comment: I think the problem has to do with differences between the type of validator we are invoking on the object  `javax.validation.Validator` vs `org.springframework.validation.Validator`

Comment: _"When I execute the above code"_ - How? Using `@Valid` annotation in controller?

Answer (score 0):

This happens because, for some reason that I don't know, Hibernate calls your *BeanSequenceProvider* more than once, and those executions pass null as an argument; however, it should still work.

That's the reason why we need a null check when creating a CustomerSequenceProvider.