# Custom bean validation

Tags: java, spring-boot, bean-validation, jsr

I'm developing an application using spring-boot. I want to validate the user bean using JSR annotation. The problem is that I have some fields that depend on the value of others. For example when status="user_pr" I have to make the address, county, and phoneNumber as mandatory.

this my bean:

```
 @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class User {

    @NotNull(message = "required")
    private String status;

    @JsonProperty("first_name")
    @NotNull(message = "required")
    private String firstName;

    @NotNull(message = "required")
    private String name;

    @NotNull(message = "required")
    @Pattern(message = "Email not valid", regexp = "^([\\w\\.\\-_]+)?\\w+@[\\w-_]+(\\.\\w+){1,}$")
    private String mailAddress;

    private String country;
    private String phoneNumber;

    @JsonProperty("address")
    private Address billingAddress;
}
```

Would you have any ideas ?

Best regards

Comment: Check the Spring Validation documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem a couple of weeks ago, I created my own validation annotation with a custom validation logic. You can find the showcase project in my repository: [ConditionalValidator](https://github.com/balag3/ConditionalValidator/tree/master).
If you have any questions, just ask.

Comment: Thanks @balag3. There is a solution that work for me too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9284450/jsr-303-validation-if-one-field-equals-something-then-these-other-fields-sho