# How to do JSR-303 constraint validation at field level based on the condition selected

Tags: spring, validation, bean-validation

I have a form with many fields i.e single and joint applications.
Based on the radio button I need to validate these fields  .

If I choose yes in radio button then single and joint fields has to be vaidated and if I choose no then single alone needs to be validated.

I need to use field level validations .How to validate  fields based on radio button?
I have gone through couple of links

Eg:
[JSR 303 Validation, If one field equals "something", then these other fields should not be null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9284450/jsr-303-validation-if-one-field-equals-something-then-these-other-fields-sho)

Above link doesn't have any annotations at **field** level.
Any body who can shed some thoughts would b appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can have custom class level validation. Check out this [link](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/java-ee-tutorial/bean-validation/class-level-constraints.html)

Comment: hi Bhushan this I already know .. how you will propogate field level error messages at class level ?