# Execute custom annotation only if JSR validation fails

Tags: spring-boot, java-8, customvalidator, jsr

I am looking for a sample code where a field is annotated with multiple validation annotations (JSR and custom). My requirement is that if validation for one annotation fails, the other annotations should not be triggered.

```
@NotNull
@Size(min=2, max=2)
@Attribute(value="OCC_TYP")
private String occupationType;
```

The @Attribute annotation is a custom validation which checks the value of the field with a column.

This @Attribute should only be triggered if other two validation fails.
Right now, when I pass a value 'D' then the error message for size is displayed as well the error message for @Attribute is displayed.

Comment: Have a look at [JSR 303 Validation, If one field equals “something”, then these other fields should not be null](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9284450/5698098); in particular [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37747771/5698098). Possibly that will already solve your requirement.

Comment: Thanks , but in my case the @Attribute should only be triggered if the JSR validation fails. I am looking for something where the result of an annotation can be used to trigger other annotation for the same field

Comment: @ShwetaliKhandelwal Actually their this no order of annotation execution defined. A way can be - check other annotation condition inside your custom annotation's validator