# Cannot resolve method 'getProperty' in 'BeanUtils'

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, hibernate-validator, apache-commons-beanutils

I'm trying to make a custom annotation using hibernate validator,found an "old" code right here on stackOverflow but there is a method called

```
BeanUtils.getProperty ()
```

which returns me the following error:

```
Cannot solve method 'getProperty' in 'BeanUtils'
```

I didn't find anything recent on the internet about it, does this method no longer exist? how can I replace it and maintain functionality?

Here the code I'm referring to:

```
package br.com.bandtec.projetocaputeam.dominio.validator;

import org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils;
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidator;
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidatorContext;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;

/**
 * Implementation of {@link NotNullIfAnotherFieldHasValue} validator.
 **/
/**
 * Implementation of {@link NotNullIfAnotherFieldHasValue} validator.
 **/
public class NotNullIfAnotherFieldHasValueValidator
        implements ConstraintValidator<NotNullIfAnotherFieldHasValue, Object> {

    private String fieldName;
    private String expectedFieldValue;
    private String dependFieldName;

    @Override
    public void initialize(NotNullIfAnotherFieldHasValue annotation) {
        fieldName          = annotation.fieldName();
        expectedFieldValue = annotation.fieldValue();
        dependFieldName    = annotation.dependFieldName();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(Object value, ConstraintValidatorContext ctx) {

        if (value == null) {
            return true;
        }

        try {
            String fieldValue       = BeanUtils.getProperty(value, fieldName);
            String dependFieldValue = BeanUtils.getProperty(value, dependFieldName);

            if (expectedFieldValue.equals(fieldValue) && dependFieldValue == null) {
                ctx.disableDefaultConstraintViolation();
                ctx.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate(ctx.getDefaultConstraintMessageTemplate())
                        .addNode(dependFieldName)
                        .addConstraintViolation();
                return false;
            }

        } catch (NoSuchMethodException | InvocationTargetException | IllegalAccessException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }

        return true;
    }

}
```

And [here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9284450/jsr-303-validation-if-one-field-equals-something-then-these-other-fields-sho/9287796#9287796) the page where I got this code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I checked the [Spring-Framework](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-beans/src/main/java/org/springframework/beans/BeanUtils.java) `BeanUtils.java`.

But there wasn't any method `getProperty()`.

Then I looked for other BeanUtils.getProperty() methods and there is the `Apache Commons` [BeanUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/).

Take a look at the class [methods/fields](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/javadocs/v1.9.3/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanUtils.html) and here the [getProperty()](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/javadocs/v1.9.3/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanUtils.html#getProperty-java.lang.Object-java.lang.String-)

You can also search the [PropertyUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/javadocs/v1.9.3/apidocs/index.html) class

Check [here](https://www.codota.com/code/java/methods/org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtils/getProperty) for examples as well.

Hope it will help. Good luck :)

Comment: Thank you! Ii've been looking for something to help me all day and I didn't even think they could be different class methods
You saved me!

Comment: That's great to hear :) We all have been in the same situationn. Keep going and good luck :)

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is bit old,but whoever wants to stick to spring framework can use the below.

```
 BeanWrapper beanWrapper = PropertyAccessorFactory.forBeanPropertyAccess(value);
 final Object actualFieldValue = beanWrapper.getPropertyValue(fieldName);
```