# want to write dynamic domain validation...is it possible to declare annotation @not null dynamically ?

Tags: java, spring, annotations

I am writing one model class in spring mvc.
I want to do domain validation.

In domain class I have 3 variables say isABCApplicable,abcValue1,abcValue2:

```
private Boolean isABCApplicable;

private BigDecimal abcValue1;

private BigDecimal abcValue2;
```

.......getters and setters.........

**Now my aim is** :

If isABCApplicable is true then i want to make abcValue1 as

```
@NotNull
 abcValue1
```

and

```
@NotNull 
abcValue2
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is possible by **bytecode instrumentation**. ASM is one such tool you can manipulate Java bytecode with. Have a look at http://asm.ow2.org/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want use annotations?
Create your own DataBinder for your model-object and do all validation in object constructor.
Or if you realy want annotations, you can write your own constraint like @NotNullIfApplicable, see [Cross field validation with Hibernate Validator (JSR 303)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972933/cross-field-validation-with-hibernate-validator-jsr-303) for details.