# BeanValidation is not evaluating Constraints on Type-level

Tags: bean-validation

BeanValidation works on normal Validations which are placed at FIELD-level:

```
@Email
@Column(unique = true)
private String email;
```

However, placing a custom constraint on TYPE-Level:

```
@Entity
@UniqueEmail
public class UserAccount { 

  @Email
  @Column(unique = true)
  private String email;
... 
}
```

with the annotation being:

```
@Constraint(validatedBy = {UniqueEmailValidator.class})
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface UniqueEmail { ... }
```

will not work. The `UniqueEmailValidator` is never called unless I programatically trigger it by calling `.validate()` on an injected `javax.validation.Validator`

Is this expected behaviour or can that be changed in a way that the BeanValidation will also evaluate custom constraints on type level.

Comment: If you are talking about Bean Valiadtion in general, type level constraints are for sure executed, especially for calls to Validator#validate calls. Any chance you are using Bean Validation with JSF? In this case this question is really a duplicate of for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11972419/cross-field-bean-validation-why-you-no-work. JSF does not call Validator#validate, but rather Validator#validateProperty.

Comment: Yes, I'm using the BeanValidation with JSF - had that in the titel originally. Thanks for the redirect.