# how to get JSR303 failures to display error in page

Tags: bean-validation

I am following the acccepted answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972933/cross-field-validation-with-hibernate-validator-jsr-303)

And it seems to work, but I don't get any of the messages back in my page when failing validation.  I have the form:errors tag with appropriate path.  But alas you get returned to the page with no errors displayed.  How do I get the errors displayed like they are with regular JSR-303 validation?

Comment: What integration technology are you using? JSF? The code you are referring to only shows the pure Bean Validation side of things. Where or what triggers validation in your case. That's where you have too look.

Comment: @Hardy an annotation like the following triggers validation on a field `@CheckDoubleEmpty(first="loadPoundsAnHour", second="ignoreFields", message="This field must be filled.")`  I have a jspx based front end.  I have @Valid notation on my bean on my controller as it is passed in to the controller method.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, in the failure scenarios in the validator, you just need to use the following.

`constraintContext.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate( "A value must be provided for this field." ).addNode( firstFieldName ).addConstraintViolation();`