# Phone Number is 3 fields in Springs model but I only want one validation error

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-validator

In the current project I am working on the model bean has the phone number in 3 fields but we only would like one spring validation error.  Can this be done>

```
@NotEmpty(message = "Your Question must not be blank.")
@Size(min = 10, max = 200)
private String content;

@NotEmpty(message = "Area Code must not be blank.")
@Size(min = 3, max = 3, message = "Area must be 3 numbers")
private String areacode;

@NotEmpty(message = "Phone Number must not be blank.")
@Size(min = 3, max = 3, message = "phone number first part must be 3 numbers")
private String phone3;

@NotEmpty(message = "Phone Number must not be blank.")
@Size(min = 4, max = 4, message = "Phone number last part must be 4 numbers")
private String phone4;
```

Comment: You have two choices: 1) remove your validation from each of the phone number fields and instead create a [JSR-3030 class-level constraint](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.3/reference/en-US/html_single/#d0e341) that can validate all the fields together.  OR 2) as you are using Spring, you could code a [Spring Validator](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#validator) for this.  I would favour the JSR-303 constraint if you are prepared to do the dev.

Answer (score 1):

If it does not matter whenever the validation error occur at class level, but not at the field, then you can use hibernate validations [ScriptAssert](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.1/api/org/hibernate/validator/constraints/ScriptAssert.html) Validation

```
@ScriptAssert(
     lang="javascript"
     script="_this.areacode!=null and _this.phone3!=null and _this.phone4!=null"
 )
public class YourClass {
     private String areacode;
     private String phone3;
     private String phone4;
}
```

For more an other idea have a look at the crossfield validation discussions/questions.
[Cross field validation with Hibernate Validator (JSR 303)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972933/cross-field-validation-with-hibernate-validator-jsr-303)