# Java jsr 303 accessing bean fields from annotated field

Tags: java, annotations

In my scenario I'm trying to create annotation that validates if one field is filled if another one has some kind of value.

The interface looks like this:

```
@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = RequiredIfFieldHasValueValidator.class)
public @interface RequiredIfFieldHasValue
{
    String message() default "Required if selected";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

    /*
    FieldName against which we validate
     */
    String fieldName() default "";

    /*
    Field value that indicates requirement
     */
    String fieldValue() default "";
}
```

And implementation:

```
public class RequiredIfFieldHasValueValidator implements ConstraintValidator<RequiredIfFieldHasValue, String>
{
    private String fieldName;
    private String fieldValue;

    @Override
    public void initialize( RequiredIfFieldHasValue constraintAnnotation )
    {
        fieldName = constraintAnnotation.fieldName();
        fieldValue = constraintAnnotation.fieldValue();
        validateParameters();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid( String value, ConstraintValidatorContext context )
    {
        System.out.println( "Validate against fieldname: " + fieldName + " fieldvalue: " + fieldValue );
        //
        //Validation should be here (1)
        //
        return false;
    }

    private void validateParameters()
    {
        if ( "".equals( fieldName ) || fieldName == null )
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException( "The fieldname cannot be null" );
        }
    }
}
```

And example usage:

```
public class Form {
    private String type;
    @RequiredIfFieldHasValue(fieldName = "type", fieldValue = "DICT")
    private String dictValue;
}
```

I use it in Spring MVC and validate on request like this:

```
public String myFormPostPost( Model model, @Valid @ModelAttribute MyForm form, indingResult result )
```

So my goal is: `If field type has value equal to DICT, field dictValue should be required (not empty)`.

My question is if I can access current bean values in `Validation should be here (1)`? I know I could do annotation to whole bean, but I'd prefere it that way.

Comment: Do you have to use a bean? If you use a builder instead, you can do that kind of validation at `.build()` time without having to use an annotation.

Comment: Could you be more specific or provide some example? Maybe I should mention that I use it in Spring MVC and validate on request like this: `public String myFormPostPost( Model model,
                                        @Valid @ModelAttribute
                                        MyForm form, BindingResult result )`

Comment: Well, you should actually mention Spring MVC, yes, and add the relevant tag(s?). I don't do Spring, so I don't know whether you can use that pattern with it.

Comment: Should have, sorry my bad :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I guess it's not possible, so I stick with class anotated solution:
[Cross field validation with Hibernate Validator (JSR 303)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972933/cross-field-validation-with-hibernate-validator-jsr-303)