# GWT JSR303 Validation, validate method OR use custom annotations

Tags: validation, gwt, hibernate-validator

I'm trying to use GWT's 2.5 in-build validation feature. I have a few complex validations.
[Cross field validation with Hibernate Validator (JSR 303)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972933/cross-field-validation-with-hibernate-validator-jsr-303) suggests that I could either include methods which do the validation OR write my own annotations. However, both don't work.

```
public class PageData extends Serializable
    @NotNull(message="Cannot be null!")
    Boolean value

    @AssertTrue(message="isValid() is false!")
    private boolean isValid() {
        return false;
    }

    //Getters and Setters
}
```

*Boolean value* is validated. However, *isValid()* is never called/validated. But why?
Is this a GWt specific problem?

Then I tried to write my own annotation, The @FieldMatch example in [Cross field validation with Hibernate Validator (JSR 303)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972933/cross-field-validation-with-hibernate-validator-jsr-303) uses Beans.getProperty() from Apache Commons BeanUtils, which I cannot use in GWT. Is there any way to make these kind of complex annotations work in GWT?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how I created a custom validation that works across multiple fields of one bean. It checks that when the field ContactProfile for a Contact bean is set to COMPANY, then company name must be filled out, otherwise when set to PERSON, the first name or last name must be filled out :

**Annotation definition :**

```
@Target({ ElementType.TYPE })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = ValidCompanyOrPersonValidator.class)
public @interface ValidCompanyOrPerson {

    String message() default "{contact.validcompanyorperson}";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Contact>[] payload() default {};
}
```

**Implementation :**

```
public class ValidCompanyOrPersonValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ValidCompanyOrPerson, Contact> {

    ValidCompanyOrPerson annotation;

    public void initialize(ValidCompanyOrPerson annotation) {
        this.annotation = annotation;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("nls")
    public boolean isValid(Contact contact, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        boolean ret = false;
        if (contact.getContactProfile() == null) {
        } else if (contact.getContactProfile().equals(ContactProfile.COMPANY)) {
            ret = (contact.getCompanyName() != null);
        } else if (contact.getContactProfile().equals(ContactProfile.PERSON)) {
            ret = (contact.getGivenName() != null || contact.getFamilyName() != null);
        }
        return ret;
    }
}
```

Now I can set

```
@ValidCompanyOrPerson
public class Contact  {
 ...
}
```

I can use this validation both client (GWT) and server side.

Hope that helps ....

Comment: @xybrek yes, it does.

Comment: What is the ValidCompanyOrPerson annotation; for? When it is not used? Just curious

Comment: @xybrek my contact class as an enum field type that can be set to person or company; the validator ensures that when marked as person, the field givenName or familyName is not null and when marked as company, the companyName is not null.