# Cross Field Validation JSR303

Tags: hibernate, validation, spring-webflow, bean-validation, apache-commons-beanutils

This is in continuation to the question asked below :

[Cross field validation with Hibernate Validator (JSR 303)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972933/cross-field-validation-with-hibernate-validator-jsr-303)

I'm new to JSR 303, my requirement is - In my page (i'm using Spring WebFlow to create a survey) I've two text fields say Amount1 and Amount2, if Amount2 is less than Amount1 then I need to show a validation error message just below Amount2 field saying (Amount2 can't be less than Amount1). Using the answer given in question above I can see this message at the top of page but not below the field.

What works:

```
@Amount(amount1= "amount1", amount2= "amount2")
public class SurveyBean extends ModelContextBean implements Serializable{
```

What is not working:

```
public class SurveyBean extends ModelContextBean implements Serializable{
@Amount(amount1= "amount1", amount2= "amount2")
private String getAmount2(){}
```

Could anyone please help me out as to how to apply cross field validation at field level...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not really a Bean Validation or Hibernate Validator question. The problem is in the UI. I have no idea how the mapping in Spring WebFlow from constraint error to field works, but I would expect that there is a way to customize it. From a Bean Validation point of view the only way to compare two fields of the same bean is to use a custom class level constraint. There is just no other way. The problem here is that the automatic mapping of error messages to fields. Thinking a bit more about it, putting the message at the top as seems to happen now, makes sense for Spring Web Flow. It is a class level constraints after all and it cannot know which fields it applies to.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that cross field validation could be applied only at class-level