# How add constrain while mapping list in hibernate

Tags: hibernate

Hibernate Mapping:
I have table called company and employee.
company has list of employees
**In Employee table i have field called boolean:enable, Now, If enable=false means then the record should not added to the company employees list..How to do it..**
Please any one help me.......

```
<class >
<id name="company_id" type="java.lang.String">
        <column name="COMPANY_ID" />
        <generator class="assigned" />
</id>
<property name="name" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="NAME" not-null="true"/>
</property>
.
.
.
<list name="employees"
                table="employee"
                fetch="join"
                cascade="all">
                <key column="company_id"/>
                <list-index column="INDEX_IN_COMPANY"/>
                <one-to-many class="com....Employee" />

</list>
</class >
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it by using Hibernate Validator. One example is shown in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972933/cross-field-validation-with-hibernate-validator-jsr-303). 
In your case you would need an annotation at the class level (Company) that accepts two properties - employees and the enable property. The validator then validates in the isValid() method.