# How to validate that date in future in reference to another date?

Tags: java, validation, date, spring-mvc, hibernate-validator

I have following bean:

```
class CampaignBeanDto {

    @Future
    Date startDate;

    Date endDate;

    ...
}
```

Obviously I that `endDate` should be after startDate. I want to validate it.

I know that I can manually realize annotation for `@FutureAfterDate`, validator for this and initialize threshold date manually but I want to use `@Validated` spring mvc annotation.

How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're gonna have to bear down and write yourself a Validator.

This should get you started:

[Cross field validation with Hibernate Validator (JSR 303)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972933/cross-field-validation-with-hibernate-validator-jsr-303)

Comment: trouble that startDate will be known only in runtime. or do uou offer use reflection to get startDate value ?

Comment: validation passes annotated field only to validate. I know endDate value how could I know  startDate value ?

Comment: @gstackoverflow follow the example I linked to. My snippet was wrong and I removed it

Answer (score 6):

You should not use Annotations for cross field validation, write a validating function instead. Explained in [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2155576/12001098) to the Question, [*Cross field validation with Hibernate Validator (JSR 303)*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1972933/642706).

For example write a validator function like this:

```
public class IncomingData {

  @FutureOrPresent
  private Instant startTime;

  @Future
  private Instant endTime;

  public Boolean validate() {
      return startTime.isBefore(endTime);
  }
}
```

Then simply call the validator function when first receiving the data:

```
if (Boolean.FALSE.equals(incomingData.validate())) {
  response = ResponseEntity.status(422).body(UNPROCESSABLE);
}
```