# How to replace implementation of javax.validation.Valid annotation in Spring?

Tags: spring, validation, bean-validation

Suppose I don't wanna use JSR 303 to validate my beans. Is it possible to implement custom validator which will be used by Spring when bean is marked as `@Valid`?

It would be great if my custom validator will be a Spring Component

Answer (score 1):

@fedor.belov

I detailed this problem in another question. In my needs I want to keep JSR-303 and make custom validator works, but you can change my example code to fit your needs.

This problem can be solved extending the LocalValidatorFactoryBean, you can override the `validate` method inside this class giving any behavior that you want.

In my case I need to use JSR-303 AND custom validators for same model in different methods in same Controller, normally is recommended to use @InitBinder, but it is not sufficient for my case because InitBinder make a bind between Model and Validator (if you use @RequestBody InitBinder is just for one model and one validator per Controller).

Controller

```
@RestController
public class LoginController {

    @PostMapping("/test")
    public Test test(@Validated(TestValidator.class) @RequestBody Test test) {
        return test;
    }

    @PostMapping("/test2")
    public Test test2(@Validated @RequestBody Test test) {
        return test;
    }
}
```

Custom Validator

```
public class TestValidator implements org.springframework.validation.Validator {

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        return Test.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz);
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
        Test test = (Test) target;
        errors.rejectValue("field3", "weird");
        System.out.println(test.getField1());
        System.out.println(test.getField2());
        System.out.println(test.getField3());
     }
}
```

Class to be validate

```
public class Test {

    @Size(min = 3)
    private String field2;

    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    private String field1;

    @NotNull
    @Past
    private LocalDateTime field3;

    //...
    //getter/setter
    //...
}
```

CustomLocalValidatorFactoryBean

```
public class CustomLocalValidatorFactoryBean extends LocalValidatorFactoryBean {

    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @Override
    public void validate(@Nullable Object target, Errors errors, @Nullable Object... validationHints) {
        Set<Validator> concreteValidators = new LinkedHashSet<>();
        Set<Class<?>> interfaceGroups = new LinkedHashSet<>();
        extractConcreteValidatorsAndInterfaceGroups(concreteValidators, interfaceGroups, validationHints);
        proccessConcreteValidators(target, errors, concreteValidators);
        processConstraintViolations(super.validate(target, interfaceGroups.toArray(new Class<?>[interfaceGroups.size()])), errors);
    }

    private void proccessConcreteValidators(Object target, Errors errors, Set<Validator> concreteValidators) {
        for (Validator validator : concreteValidators) {
            validator.validate(target, errors);
        }
    }

    private void extractConcreteValidatorsAndInterfaceGroups(Set<Validator> concreteValidators, Set<Class<?>> groups, Object... validationHints) {
        if (validationHints != null) {
            for (Object hint : validationHints) {
                if (hint instanceof Class) {
                    if (((Class<?>) hint).isInterface()) {
                        groups.add((Class<?>) hint);
                    } else {
                        Optional<Validator> validatorOptional = getValidatorFromGenericClass(hint);
                        if (validatorOptional.isPresent()) {
                            concreteValidators.add(validatorOptional.get());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private Optional<Validator> getValidatorFromGenericClass(Object hint) {
        try {
            Class<Validator> clazz = (Class<Validator>) Class.forName(((Class<?>) hint).getName());
            return Optional.of(clazz.newInstance());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            logger.info("There is a problem with the class that you passed to "
                    + " @Validated annotation in the controller, we tried to "
                    + " cast to org.springframework.validation.Validator and we cant do this");
        }
        return Optional.empty();
    }

}
```

Configure application

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public javax.validation.Validator localValidatorFactoryBean() {
        return new CustomLocalValidatorFactoryBean();
    }
}
```

Input to `/test` endpoint:

```
{
    "field1": "",
    "field2": "aaaa",
    "field3": "2018-04-15T15:10:24"
}
```

Output from `/test` endpoint:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2018-04-16T17:34:28.532+0000",
    "status": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "errors": [
        {
            "codes": [
                "weird.test.field3",
                "weird.field3",
                "weird.java.time.LocalDateTime",
                "weird"
            ],
            "arguments": null,
            "defaultMessage": null,
            "objectName": "test",
            "field": "field3",
            "rejectedValue": "2018-04-15T15:10:24",
            "bindingFailure": false,
            "code": "weird"
        },
        {
            "codes": [
                "NotEmpty.test.field1",
                "NotEmpty.field1",
                "NotEmpty.java.lang.String",
                "NotEmpty"
            ],
            "arguments": [
                {
                    "codes": [
                        "test.field1",
                        "field1"
                    ],
                    "arguments": null,
                    "defaultMessage": "field1",
                    "code": "field1"
                }
            ],
            "defaultMessage": "Não pode estar vazio",
            "objectName": "test",
            "field": "field1",
            "rejectedValue": "",
            "bindingFailure": false,
            "code": "NotEmpty"
        }
    ],
    "message": "Validation failed for object='test'. Error count: 2",
    "path": "/user/test"
}
```

Input to `/test2` endpoint:

```
{
    "field1": "",
    "field2": "aaaa",
    "field3": "2018-04-15T15:10:24"
}
```

Output to `/test2` endpoint:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2018-04-16T17:37:30.889+0000",
    "status": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "errors": [
        {
            "codes": [
                "NotEmpty.test.field1",
                "NotEmpty.field1",
                "NotEmpty.java.lang.String",
                "NotEmpty"
            ],
            "arguments": [
                {
                    "codes": [
                        "test.field1",
                        "field1"
                    ],
                    "arguments": null,
                    "defaultMessage": "field1",
                    "code": "field1"
                }
            ],
            "defaultMessage": "Não pode estar vazio",
            "objectName": "test",
            "field": "field1",
            "rejectedValue": "",
            "bindingFailure": false,
            "code": "NotEmpty"
        }
    ],
    "message": "Validation failed for object='test'. Error count: 1",
    "path": "/user/test2"
}
```

[Original answer with original question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49863262/3694570).

I hope this help.

Comment: I'm getting working while calling this endpoint: `There is a problem with the class that you passed to  @Validated annotation in the controller, we tried to cast to org.springframework.validation.Validator and we cant do this`

Comment: Hi @PranayKumbhalkar, do you trying to cast `TestValidator.class` to org.springframework.validation.Validator? Why do you trying to make it?

Comment: Works great, thank you. Personally I just use the class *CustomLocalValidatorFactoryBean* and override *processConstraintViolations* to throw a custom exception based on the violations (allows to populate the response with a business error code, concatenate error messages if there are several, etc). Also, you can just annotate the class with *@Configuration* instead of declaring it in the root class *Application*.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to implement `Validator` interface and mark the implementation as `@Component`. Then you can bind your custom validator using `@InitBinder` annotation. Something like this:

```
@Component
public class MyCustomValidator implements Validator
{

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz)
    {
        // your custom logic
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(Object target, Errors errors)
    {
        // your custom logic
    }
}
```

To bind it with annotation:

```
@Controller
public class MyController
{
    @Autowired
    private MyCustomValidator validator;

    @InitBinder
    protected void initBinder(final WebDataBinder binder)
    {
        binder.addValidators(validator);
    }
}
```

Comment: This approach requires a lot of boilerplate code in a controller. Final implementation should require only @Valid annotation (or any other custom one)