# Spring validation with checking a dictionary

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, validation

Using Spring RestControllers with hibernate validator.

Need to create some Validation annotation, that check the validating field presents in some dictionary (preset array or some DB).

For example, I have some bean

```
@Service
public class MyDict {

   public boolean containsWord(String word) {
       ...
   }
}
```

And some data, I check

```
public class ResponseData {

    @IsInDictionary(MyDict.class)
    private String word;

}
```

And when I call hibernate validation directly, or with `@Valid` annotation in RequestMapping method, I want validator to call MyDict bean method containsWord(word).

Does anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define your own annotation and then define your own `Validator` where you will be performing your validation logic (in this case, a dictionary lookup)

You can read more about this here: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.1/reference/en-US/html/validator-customconstraints.html#validator-customconstraints-constraintannotation

After creating your own annotation, you just extend `ConstraintValidator<YourCustomAnnotation, String>` and you are pretty much ready to go. Method `isValid()` needs to perform inside the logic you mentioned: `containsWord(word)`

The nice thing is that your custom validator can be a Spring-managed bean so you can freely inject stuff into it and for example, perform a DB lookup. So in this case, you would need to inject your dictionaries and perform a check there.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, if I mention my own validator as spring bean, my bean (not another instance of my class) will be used as validator? I'd like to check it today, but I'm skeptic)

Comment: @dmitryvim If you create your own annotation, there is a predefined mechanisms was using it for validation. Simply put, you just need to extend ConstraintValidator properly and you should be good to go. I've done this recently and it works :)