# Custom validator in spring mvc to check if one of the checkbox is selected or not

Tags: thymeleaf, spring-validator

I have few fields in my pojo class which are being represented as checkbox on UI.

```
private String borrowerEthnicity1;
private String borrowerEthnicity2;
private Integer borrowerEthnicity3;
private Integer borrowerEthnicity4;
private Integer borrowerEthnicity5;
private Integer borrowerEthnicity3;
private Integer borrowerEthnicity7;
```

I want to validate if at least one of the checkbox is being checked. I am creating my custom annotation but no luck. Please help me on this.

Comment: Annotation, does it mean you use JSR-303/349 (Bean Validation API)?

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cross field validation with Hibernate Validator (JSR 303)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972933/cross-field-validation-with-hibernate-validator-jsr-303)

Comment: thank you for your reply. I got it ..:)