# Date Attribute Validation, End Date must be greater than start date -Spring Boot

Tags: java, validation, datetime, spring-boot

I need to check if an End Date is greater than start Date in Back side.
I've read about validators but I don't know how to use them and I am wondering if there's another alternative(add constraint as Annotation Maybe ..).

Any recommendation or suggestion would be great!

Comment: where store start and end time? Is it store on one DTO?

Comment: Yes ,they belong to the same entity

Comment: Why you don't implement it by yourself? You could create Interface Validator<T> with validate(T t) method. After validation return boolean or List<ErrorMessage> or throw new excpetion

Comment: it seems to be the best solution and I am working on it now, if you have any good validators' examples ,it would be so helpful

Comment: Please refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972933/cross-field-validation-with-hibernate-validator-jsr-303/2155576#2155576). Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

There is no spring annotation for such validation. 
You can do it on your own like plain oldshool over the setter:

```
public class MyEntity... {
    ...
    private LocalDate shouldBeAfterNow;

    public void setShouldBeAfterNow(LocalDate date) {
         if(date.isAfter(LocalDate.now())) {
           shouldBeAfterNow = date;
         } else {
           throw new SomeException(); // or
         }
    }
    ...
}
```

**But please consider if you really need such validation in the entity**. Maybe there is a better place for this... maybe the service or mapper class.

Answer (score -1):

In your method you can use an Assertion:
`Assert.isTrue(endDate.isAfter(startDate),"Custom message");`

The custom message is optional.

Comment: hello, Which method do you mean ? I only have attributes and want to check on them

Comment: I'm assuming you create an object with the dates as parameters? Before creating the object ( or in the constructor ) you can add this to check the dates. If you could provide some example code I can have a better picture of your situation :)